# Populating and calculating data across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create a multiple sheet workbook, where 1 main sheet summarizes and populates data from the other sheets in the same workbook.

I had tried using pivot tables, but it's not aggregating the results the way I want it to.
I thought VLookup might help, but I am clueless as to how to use it in this context.

I made the excel file noting down what I want it to actually show, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

it is very elementary, so apologies for that but feel free to take a look
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Upp4u1OPcyPADHnnL-nKqwlzSIJu7cV_/view

Comment: Since none of us know what you're trying to achieve and many of us won't download files from unknown sources, I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56938088/edit) to include what data you have, what you want to achieve, what you've tried and how it fails to provide the expected result.

Comment: Every sheet in the workbook, except the main sheet, will have the same format and cells (with different info)???